# Python iterating through file, "Unresolved attribute reference 'strip' for class 'int'" warning: is it PyCharm or is it me?

Tags: python, pycharm

As part of something I'm writing, when iterating through a file (using enumerate so I can get line numbers) PyCharm gives me the warning `Unresolved attribute reference 'strip' for class 'int'` when I try and strip my strings.
Stripped down the essentials, the code is:

```python
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as my_list:
    for line, line_num in enumerate(my_list, start=1):
        line = line.strip() # < Warning is here
        my_bits = line.split("|")
        # What I'm doing here isn't important
        # I'm just showing I use string methods on it without further errors
```

I can select to ignore it in PyCharm, so this isn't a world-ending situation. But I would like to know: could I be coding it better or is PyCharm just too quick to make assumptions?

Comment: You have the return values of `enumerate()` backwards.  The line number is _first_, not second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumerate` returns the index first, then the item. Should be:

```
for line_num, line in enumerate(my_list, start=1):
    ...
```

Probably what is going on is that `strip` returns a string value like it is supposed to, and since you assign the return value back into `line`, there's no longer a reason for a warning, since you're applying a str method validly to a str object.
Step by step:

```
line = 1
s = line.strip() # WARNING: 1 is an int, but I'm assuming what you wanted was '1'.strip()
# s is now the stripped version of '1', i.e. '1'
line = s
# line is now '1'
my_bits = line.split('|') # No problem
#my_bits is now ['1']
```

Comment: Thanks! I was only ever using the line number to print() in case of an error, which never really happened, so didn't notice that the line number was an awfully long string.